# do i need to install mongodb-runner when installing parse even thought mongodb is already insstalled

Tags: mongodb, installation, parse-server

i am installing parse server on linux vps , i have already installed nodejs and mongo db and now i am following what is written here https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server 
when i try to execute $ mongodb-runner start
i have this error

```
◟ Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...✔  Downloaded MongoDB 4.2.0
◠ Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...mongodb-runner:bin:mongodb-r                    unner-worker.js Unexpected error. Exiting. { Error: Command failed: mongod --set                    Parameter enableTestCommands=1 --port 27017 --dbpath /home/admoon/.mongodb/data/                    standalone --logpath /home/admoon/.mongodb/runner/standalone.log
mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared o                    bject file: No such file or directory

 at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:294:12)
 at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
 at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
 at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
killed: false,
code: 127,
signal: null,
cmd:
'mongod --setParameter enableTestCommands=1 --port 27017 --dbpath /home/admoo                    n/.mongodb/data/standalone --logpath /home/admoon/.mongodb/runner/standalone.log                    ',
output:
{ stderr:
   [ 'mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open                     shared object file: No such file or directory',
     '' ],
  stdout: [ '' ] } }
```

Comment: No. You can setup your Parse Server to connect to your existing MongoDB.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to install mongo-db runner when you have mongodb installed 
thanks to @DaviMacedo

Comment: Is there any way to import mongodb data from back4app cloud db to locale?

Comment: @OmInfowaveDevelopers try to reach back4app support and they will help you out.
In back4app there is no vendor-lock in, you can smoothly switch to self hosted parse-server at any time.
I hope this was helpful.